# how to push the array of objects data into another array with matching uid

Tags: reactjs

hello i am getting two api's (one api with authentication and another api without authentication) data from the backend , items and wishes....now i want to push that wishes objects into items array with mathcing uid....can anyone help me on this

code sand box link : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-oky3q?file=/demo.js:0-1678

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";

    class Wish extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          items: [
            { uid: "1001", item: "iPhone" },
            { uid: "1002", item: "iPad" },
            { uid: "1003", item: "iTab" },
            { uid: "1004", item: "iTelevision" }
          ],
          wishes: [
            { uid: "1001", wish: true },
            { uid: "1002", wish: false },
            { uid: "1003", wish: true },
            { uid: "1004", item: false }
          ]
        };
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <TableContainer>
              <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>UID</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">Item</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left">Wish</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {this.state.items.map((item) => (
                    <TableRow key={item.name}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {item.uid}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">{item.item}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">{item.fat}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Wish;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a map of `uid`'s to items, then merge in the wishes.

```
const itemsObj = this.state.items.reduce((itemsObj, item) => {
  return {
    ...itemsObj,
    [item.uid]: item,
  }
}, {});

const merged = this.state.wishes.reduce((mergedObj, {uid, wish}) => {
  return {
    ...mergedObj,
    [uid]: {
      ...mergedObj[uid],
      wish
    }
  }
}, itemsObj);
```

When you render, use `Object.values(merged)` to get an array of the merged values.

```
{Object.values(merged).map((item) => (
  <TableRow key={item.name}>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      {item.uid}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{item.item}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{(!!item.wish).toString()}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
))}
```

This saves the need to search the wishes array each iteration of the second pass over the wishes array to merge `wish`, i.e. `O(1)` item lookup versus `O(n)` search in wishes array, the overall complexity being `O(n)` versus `O(n^2)`.

[image: Edit how-to-push-the-array-of-objects-data-into-another-array-with-matching-uid]

Comment: thanks very much Drew Reese...for your answer....:)

Comment: Hello Drew....instead of using this Object.values(merged)....is there any another way to use....loop...juts like Items.map

Comment: @ManoharPamishetty You are looping, technically, but `merged` is an object that was used in order to get the `O(1)` constant time key lookup into the items object, but there's the last step of converting the object's values back into an array so that you *can* do the mapping for the JSX. The alternative is using a [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to push the values into an array that you can then map, but this can't be done in an in-line functional programming way.

Comment: hi @Drew Reese , could please help on this code , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802632/how-to-change-flag-dynamically-in-material-ui-multiple-auto-complete

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to merge them to get { uid, item, wish }, then just do

```
const merged = state.items.map(item => ({
    // dump all of item into the new object
    ...item, 
    // add in wish from the matching uids
    // if there's a chance no wish can be found, 
    // add in a fallback value
    wish: state.wishes.find(wish => wish.uid === item.uid).wish
    })
)
```

then instead of `this.state.items.map((item) =>`, use `merged.map((item) =>`

and instead of `<TableCell align="left">{item.fat}</TableCell>`, use `<TableCell align="left">{item.wish.toString()}</TableCell>`

See updated sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pkk64

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Basically create new array and check if uid is match dump all previous data as well as new wish uid value:

```js
const data = {
          items: [
            { uid: "1001", item: "iPhone" },
            { uid: "1002", item: "iPad" },
            { uid: "1003", item: "iTab" },
            { uid: "1004", item: "iTelevision" }
          ],
          wishes: [
            { uid: "1001", wish: true },
            { uid: "1002", wish: false },
            { uid: "1003", wish: true },
            { uid: "1004", item: false }
          ]
        };
    

const newData = data.items.map(test => {
  const wishesLikeObj = data.wishes.find(m => m.uid=== test.uid);
  console.log(test,wishesLikeObj)
  if(wishesLikeObj.uid){
    return {
      ...test,
      wish:wishesLikeObj.wish
    }
  }
  return data
})

console.log(newData)
```